# Function to return element of JSON or Variant field

Tags: sql, function, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need help in creating a function in which i pass on table and column(containing array) and it returns required element of array.

`CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE json_table (v variant); INSERT INTO json_table SELECT parse_json( '{ "fullName":"Robert Downey", "age":55, "gender":"Male", "address": { "areaCode":"91506", "suite":"916 West Burbank Blvd" }, "movies": [ {"name":"Iron Man",       "budget":"$150M","producer":"Avi Arad"}, {"name":"Sherlock Holmes","budget":"$200M","producer":"Joel Silver"}, {"name":"Dolittle",       "budget":"$175M","producer":"Joe Roth"} ] }');`

sp(tablename, input_column, input_level optoinal, out_column);
call sp('json_table', 'v', 'fullName');
return: "Robert Downey"

sp(tablename, input_column, input_level optoinal, out_column);
call sp('json_table', 'v', 'name', 'movies');
return:
"Iron Man"
"Sherlock Holmes"
"Dolittle"

NOT SURE WHAT SHOULD WE RETURN STRING, ARRAY OR TABLE ...

Answer (score 0):

To implement the first case, here is the example.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE json_table (v variant);

INSERT INTO json_table
SELECT parse_json( '{ "fullName":"Robert Downey", "age":55, "gender":"Male", "address": { "areaCode":"91506", "suite":"916 West Burbank Blvd" }, "movies": [ {"name":"Iron Man",       "budget":"$150M","producer":"Avi Arad"}, {"name":"Sherlock Holmes","budget":"$200M","producer":"Joel Silver"}, {"name":"Dolittle",       "budget":"$175M","producer":"Joe Roth"} ] }'); 

INSERT INTO json_table
SELECT parse_json( '{ "fullName":"Goun Na", "age":55, "gender":"Male", "address": { "areaCode":"91506", "suite":"916 West Burbank Blvd" }, "movies": [ {"name":"Iron Man",       "budget":"$150M","producer":"Avi Arad"}, {"name":"Sherlock Holmes","budget":"$200M","producer":"Joel Silver"}, {"name":"Dolittle",       "budget":"$175M","producer":"Joe Roth"} ] }'); 


select * from  json_table;
select v:fullName::String from json_table;

create or replace procedure sp(tablename varchar, input_column varchar, out_column varchar)
returns table (res varchar)
language sql
as
$$
declare
    qry string;
    res resultset;
begin
    qry := 'select v:'||:out_column||'::String'||' from '||:tablename;
    res := (execute immediate qry);
    return table(res);
end;
$$
;

call sp('json_table', 'v', 'fullName');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example for the second case:

```sql
select f.value:name::String from json_table, table(flatten(v:movies)) f;

create or replace procedure sp2(tablename varchar, input_column varchar, input_level varchar, out_column varchar)
returns table (res varchar)
language sql
as
$$
declare
  qry string;
  res resultset;
begin
  qry := 'select f.value:'||:input_level||'::String from '||:tablename||', table(flatten('||:input_column||':movies)) f';
  res := (execute immediate qry);
  return table(res);
end;
$$
;

call sp2('json_table', 'v', 'name', 'movies');
```

Comment: Thanks @Goun Na

Small change in the query:

  qry := 'SELECT f.value:'||:input_level||'::String FROM '||:tablename||', table(flatten('||:input_column|| ':' ||:out_column||')) f';

Comment: Please update your first answer instead of adding another